# Does google chrome frame support websocket?

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-frame

Does google chrome frame support websocket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, Chrome Frame [supports websockets](http://jwebsocket.org/index.htm?page=browsers.htm). I'm not sure, but it may also depend on the Chrome version you have installed. I have 5.0.317 and [this](http://jwebsocket.org/chat.htm) websockets demo works inside IE.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting in the Google Chrome developer channel release 4.0.249.0, Web Sockets are available and enabled by default. Web Sockets are "TCP for the Web," a next-generation bidirectional communication technology for web applications being standardized in part of Web Applications 1.0. We've implemented this feature as described in our design docs for WebKit  and Chromium.

http://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/web-sockets-now-available-in-google.html

Comment: Yeah I know, but what about chrome frame?

Comment: @Michael This picture is worth 50 words, literally.

@Jourkey Check the latest available version of Chrome Frame. If it's >= 4.0.249.0, then it has WebSockets support.